# F# Generative Type Provider with Units of Measure

Tags: f#, type-providers, units-of-measurement

I am encountering an odd error with a Generative Type Provider that creates types with properties annotated with units of measure.  To keep things simple, the Units of Measure are the built-in SI units.

The type provider builds and can be referenced from other projects.  The other projects build successfully, until I reference the aforementioned property.

In Visual Studio, if I hover over the type,

`let collision = new MAVLink.Messages.COLLISION()`

Then the type definition appears in the tooltip, including the properties with annotated units of measure:
`member TIME : float32<second> with get, set`

Everything builds, until I reference the property:

`let t = collision.TIME`

In which case I get an error: `Invalid number of generic arguments to type 'Single' in provided type. Expected '0' arguments, given '1'.`

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this issue?

Comment: I have no idea why in your case the type `float32` (aka. `Single`) cannot receive a generic argument. Can you try to change it to `float` (aka. `float64` or `Double`)?

Comment: @Kata I did try various types, but nothing worked.  It seems that units of measure are just not possible with generated types (which makes sense, since UoM are erased.)  Simply switching to erased types fixed the issue.